# systemctl add bash command as a Environment variable

Tags: shell, systemd, environment-variables

I want to use this line as an env for systemctl file.

```bsh
Environment="PGBOUNCER_IP=$(ip -json addr show $interface |   jq -r '.[] | .addr_info[] | select(.family == "inet") | .local'| grep -v '127.0.0.1')"
```

but its not considering the value instead the whole command is taken.

I tried to put this in a file and calling from systemctl.

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'source envfile'
```

But no luck

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

```bsh
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "/bin/systemctl set-environment PGBOUNCER_IP=$(ip -json addr show $interface |   jq -r '.[] | .addr_info[] | select(.family == \"inet\") | .local'| grep -v '127.0.0.1')"
```